# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target'

Tags: reactjs

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Handler for dropdown :

```js
handlePortfolioChange = data => (event) => {
    this.resetForm();
    this.setState({ selectedPortfolio: event.target.value });
}
```

Actual SelectBox

```
<Select value={this.state.sp}
    onChange={e =>
    this.setState({sp: e.target.value
    }, this.handleChange(data, e))}
>
```

Comment: You're calling it wrong, it should be `this.handleChange(data)(e)`

Answer (score 0):

You have a *[curried](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-currying-in-javascript-ceb2188c339)* function there (it takes multiple sets of arguments). In your case `data` and `event`.

You can invoke it like this with both *particular* sets of arguments at once: `handlePortfolioChange(data)(event)` (instead of `handlePortofolioChange(data,e)`).

Maybe it's of help to mention that you can also define a more narrow function with a particular **data** object to use every time to only have to vary the **event** like this:

```
//say, you had data-object that doesn't change in this scope like constantData
constantData = {
"some": 1,
"data": 2,
"here": "idk"
}

// then you could define a more particular function that handlePortfolioChange, by passing //only the first argument to the general function:
handleConstantPortfolioData = handlePortfolioData(constantData);
```

You could then invoke it anywhere but only worry about the event:

```
...onChange={e => this.handleConstantPortfolioData(e)}...
```